# Custom Bar Button Item Image Frame Too Wide

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I am trying to add a custom icon as the image of a bar button item. I correctly added the image assets in the 1x, 2x, 3x sizes, but the frame is too wide for no apparent reason. The image itself is a square and does not have such a wide frame. Click the link below to see the issue. Is there a way to fix this?

[Extra wide frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDUFD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/) that the documentation recommends for custom icons.

You just need to resize the image as per standard.

> 1X: 25 x 25
>
> 2X: 50 x 50
>
> 3X: 75 x 75